# How to update the text in the UI from the background thread in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application I need to update the text in the UI depending upon the data from the network.For that I am using a `AsyncTask` to do work in background in Android. My code is as follows.

```
public class DefaultActivity extends Activity{

  TextView textView;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textId);
    new networkFileAccess().execute("background","Progress","result");
  }

  private class networkFileAccess extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    protected String doInBackground(String... background){
       return changeText();
    }

    private String changeText(){
     //Code to Access data from the Network.
     //Parsing the data.
     //Retrieving the boolean Value.
     if(booleanistrue){
      //Displaying some text on the UI.
      publishProgress("someTextOnUI");
      //Send request till we get get boolean value as false.
      changeText();
     }else{
       return "success";
     }
      return "";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){
      textView.setText("Wait background work is going on");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      if(result.equals("success")){
       //Code to finish the activity.
      }
    }
  }
```

}

In the above code I am able to run the background thread till I get boolean value as false.But the text is not updating on the UI. Can I update the text on the UI using `onProgressUpdate`() method by calling `publishProgress` method.?Any suggesstions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your Ui method inside runonUiTHREAD like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    tv.setText("ABC");
}
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

In AsyncTask, onPostExecute() and onPreExecute() both runs on UI thread. So you can change the text in onPostExecute() method.

Or you can also call runOnUiThread in doInBackground() method which runs in thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // change text
    }
});
```

It post runnable to run on UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the short answer is, yes, you can update UI elements in the onProgressUpdate method. OnProgressUpdate is actually invoked on the UI thread itself, so you don't need to do anything fancy.

How do you know your onProgressUpdate isn't working if it's hardcoded to "Wait background work is going on"?

Also, is there any reason why you aren't using a ProgressDialog to show the "Wait background work is going on" message to your users? It's typically more intuitive if you actually want them to wait. It displays a spinner or progress bar (your choice) that lets them know work is being done. It also doubles up as a way of preventing them from doing other stuff until your application is done processing whatever it has to.

Comment: Hi Gophermofur iam updating the text in onProgressUpdate() by calling publishProgress() method but the text is not displaying.

Comment: Here i need to display the text regarding the Maintenance of site and that depends upon the boolean value.If it is true i need to display the text otherwise i need to finish the activity.

Comment: Are you sure it goes into the publishProgress method? Have you tried putting some Log statements to see where your coding is going?