# Adding a ListView To My Client

Tags: android, sockets, android-listview

I am making a client on my android that connects to my server on my pc.  I am having problems with the listview.  I was wondering how I can add it to my **"*ClientThread*"** class so i can update it from socket inputs.  I can't find a way because it only works if i add it into the **"*onCreate*"** class but i cant use sockets in that class if you can help me ***thank you in advance***.

```
package com.example.marcus.chatclient1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class chat extends Activity {
    Handler han;
String string;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    final Button join = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joinButton);
    final EditText nameT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            join.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nameT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
            final TextView errorT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ChatList);
            final ArrayList<String> StrAr = new ArrayList<String>();
            StrAr.add("Welcome");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), R.layout.activity_chat, StrAr);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            han = new Handler(){
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    StrAr.add(string);
                }
            };
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Message message=Message.obtain();
        Socket s;
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.0.15", 55555);
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            o.writeObject("Android");
            int num = 0;
                num++;
                string = "Hello World >>" + num;
                han.sendMessage(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the `ListView` initial code in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` because you have to show your UI to users as soon as possible.

And you can use a `Thread` with a `Handler` class to get your socket input and update it to your `ListView`.Every time you get input from your socket in your child thread,use a handler to send message to the Activity's main thread to update UI.

For more details about **Handler**,read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can't change UI elements within a background. All changes to UI elements must be done in the main thread (aka UI thread).

The simplest way to address this issue would be making use of handlers.

- Declare a handler as your class member. `private Handler mHandler;`
- Instantiate it in your `onCreate` method. `mHandler = new Handler();`
- From now on, whenever you'd need to apply changes on your `ListView`, wrap your codes in a `Runnable` and post it to the main thread via `mHandler.post(myrunnable);`

---

Alternatively you can use `runOnUiThread()` of your main activity.

[How to update the text in the UI from the background thread in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450389/how-to-update-the-text-in-the-ui-from-the-background-thread-in-android)

---

Btw, I couldn't figure out what's the point of this:

```
while (true) {
    StrAr.add("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

Comment: i added one but it still doesn't work now it just closes the app when i press the button